# How to return object from database using entityManager query - Exception: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:

Tags: hibernate, entitymanager

I'm need create one query that return one User from my database by username.
So, I need that return this result in Class format (User.class)

I tried implement this code but I have one exception:

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: myDB.user is not mapped

```
public User getUserByUsername(String username){
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        User u = (User) em.createQuery("FROM myDB.user WHERE myDB.user.username = :username").setParameter(username, username);
        em.close();
        return u;
}
```

Follow my Entity Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "lastAccessed")
    private Date lastAccessed;


    /**get and setters*/
}
```

Comment: have you tried removing "myDB." from your query? have you mapped the user class into hibernate.cfg.xml ?

Comment: Hi Leviand, yes, I tried, but I have other schema in my database, so I think that I need put the name of my schema. all right? Yes my User.class already mapped in hibernate.cfg.xml.

Comment: JPQL uses entities and their fields/associations. Not tables and column names. Your entity is named `User`, not `myDB.user`. And yes, case matters.

Comment: JB, the code below works. but I would like that return an User object: check the code (its working)...

Object u = em.createNativeQuery("Select * from moto4u.user where moto4u.user.username = '"+username+"'").getSingleResult();